# Login code with PDO SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have login form and I post data in edit.php but I want SELECT if username = username login. if not echo error.

my code is here :

```
require_once "../../connect.php";

if($_POST){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];


        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usersWHERE username = $username password = $password");
            if($query){
                echo "successfull";
            }else{
                echo "no";
            }

}
```

Comment: You're doing this wrongly; use prepared statements instead of adding user-supplied information directly into your database

Comment: where is 'AND' ? in between where clauses

Comment: no debugging whatsoever  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your missing the AND

```
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password");
                                                                     ^^^
```

Comment: Also missing the space between 'users' and 'WHERE', and also missing any form of escaping for `$username` or `$password`.

Comment: forgot to mention that yes that also

Comment: username and password are strings, not integers

Comment: this will fail `WHERE username = $username AND password = $password` no idea why this was accepted "as is" and will NOT help future visitors to the question/answer.

Comment: @ me when you fixed your answer.